# How can i get relationship type at Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem like that i wanna write my own form builder at custom project with 70 models but i need to learn relationship type at eloquent and also 2 or 3 depht more.

For example:

```
class Category extends BaseModel
{
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryDetail::class);
    }
}


class CategoryDetail extends BaseModel
{
    public function extras()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Extra::class,'model');
    }
}
```

I need something like that:

```
learnMethodType(Category::class,'details');
```

Real need : data comes from builded json

```
 learnMethodType(Category::class,'details.extras');
```

return should be like:

```
['model'=> CategoryDetail::class,'type'=>'hasMany', ... other parameters];

['model'=> Extra::class,'type'=>'morphMany', 'name'=> 'model'];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this implementation?

```
function learnMethodType($classname,$method){
    $oReflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($classname);
    $method = $oReflectionClass->getMethod($method)
    $type = get_class($method->invoke($classname))
    return $type;
}
```

Or simply this:

```
function learnMethodType($classname,$method){
    $obj = new $classname;
    $type = get_class($obj->{$method}())
    return $type;
}
```

For your case you can also add

```
function get_short_class($obj){
    return (new \ReflectionClass($obj))->getShortName();
}
```

And replace get_class with get_short_class above.

[Some benchmarks](https://coderwall.com/p/cpxxxw/php-get-class-name-without-namespace) in case you are worried about the reflection class:

Comment: Hi there it worked i need hasMany model in function?

Comment: Sorry, didn't got your question?